# tcl Expect is not found in Tkinter module of python

Tags: python, tkinter, package, tcl, expect

I was trying to reuse my tcl code in python but Expect package is not importing.

```
>>> from Tkinter import *
>>> tcl = Tcl()
>>> tcl.eval('puts $tcl_version')
8.5
''
>>> tcl.eval('package require expect')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package expect
```

Please explain me how to get it working. My machine having tcl install, there Expect is working fine.

Comment: I bet it's Python trying to use its own built-in version rather than sensibly sticking with the system build. Don't know how to fix…

Comment: Yes same I want but no idea how it will work ?? Please help !!!

Answer (score 1):

Expect should be capitalized:

```
tcl.eval('package require Expect')
```

Yes, TCL is a case-sensitive language.

## Update

I have verified that my suggestion worked on my systems (Linux and Mac). Since you claimed it did not work on your system, let's do the following test:

Start the TCL shell:

```
tclsh
```

See if you can use the Expect package:

```
package require Expect
```

If you see error, that means you don't have the Expect package installed, or the path is wrong. If you don't, then your path is altered when you fired up the Python shell.

In either case, I don't have enough information to help you. If you still requiring help, please post more information such as your operating system and other details you can think of.

## Update 2

On a Windows 7 machine, I installed the ActivePython 2.7.x and observed your behavior, i.e. the Expect package not found. This happens on both 32- and 64-bit versions of ActivePython 2.7.x Next, I installed 32-bit Cygwin on the same machine and chose to include Python and Expect. This time, everything works.

At this point, you have a couple of choices:

1. use Cygwin
2. If you use 64-bit Python, you might not be able to gain access to Expect, see this [article](http://community.activestate.com/faq/where-expect).
3. If you are using 32-bit Python, the same article suggests a way to install Expect via the `teacup` command.

Comment: HI Hai, in tcl it is working but my question. But I need         >>> from Tkinter import *
>>> tcl = Tcl()
>>> tcl.eval('puts $tcl_version')
8.5
''
>>> tcl.eval('package require expect')                                                            this should work in Python. -- My os is XP and I am using python 2.7.XX -- please help